# Playstation plus account on different consoles

Tags: ps4, playstation-plus

I'm wondering if me and one of my friend could play online using only one playstation plus account but on different consoles. I mean, the user to be on both machines and playing at the same time. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. You must have the PS Plus holders account on both machines. Make one machine the home machine for that account. The person without the PS plus account must sign into that machine with their account. The other PS4 that is not the home machine must be signed into by the PS Plus subscription holder.

Note: You can only have one PS4 home machine at a time.